# What does Function.prototype.toMethod() do?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I noticed that the `Function.prototype` has a `toMethod()` method in experimental JavaScript, but what does that actually do? And how do I use it?

Comment: Perhaps related: https://esdiscuss.org/topic/any-tomethod-use-case#content-1

Comment: I've never done any mixins or class compositions when it comes to inheritance. so I still don't understand what they are talking about or how to use it

Comment: @Edwin - I don't think it's meant for use by the casual JavaScript developer. It's a very deep level function for use in advanced JavaScript libraries which depend on some features of prototype inheritance that are also in "experimental" status (like the "`super()`" function)

Comment: From [another source](https://cure53.de/es6-for-penetration-testers.pdf): "The purpose of Function.toMethod() is to provide means for accessing a method from a superclass and
generating a fresh function object with a new home."

Comment: Ok can someone write a quick script that uses two classes one that extends from another one and using the **.toMethod()** because when I called **.toMethod** on a function it returned a new function yet I'm not sure what changed. Like in **.bind** the context changes

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Update**: the `toMethod` method was experimental only and did not make it into the standard. The home object is essentially static now, the only way to manipulate `super` is to change the [[prototype]]:

```
var base = {…}; // as below
var obj = Object.setPrototypeOf({
    foo() { // needs to use method definition syntax
       super.foo();
    }
}, base);
obj.foo();
```

---

It's very similar to the `bind` method of function objects. However, instead of creating a new function with a bound `this` value, it creates a new function with a bound [`[[HomeObject]]`](http://people.mozilla.org/~jorendorff/es6-draft.html#table-28), which is the reference that is used for `super` calls:

> `[[HomeObject]]` (Object): If the function uses `super`, this is the object whose `[[GetPrototypeOf]]` provides the object where super property lookups begin.

Consider this example (not using any class syntax):

```
var base = {
    foo: function() {
         console.log("base foo called on", this);
    }
};
base.foo(); // base foo called on base
var obj = Object.create(base);
obj.foo(); // base foo called on obj

obj.foo = function() {
    super.foo();
};
obj.foo(); // ReferenceError: this method has no home
obj.bar = obj.foo.toMethod(obj);
obj.bar(); // base foo called on obj

obj.baz = function() {
    super();
};
obj.baz(); // ReferenceError: this constructor has no parent class
Reflect.setPrototypeOf(obj.baz, base.foo);
obj.baz(); // base foo called on obj
```

Comment: I understand how to use bind and that it returns a new function with a different context but the **[[HomeObject]]** that I don't understand

Comment: I've now added an example on how `super` could be used

Comment: I'm not familiar with how this all works, but it seems like it should be `obj.bar = obj.foo.toMethod(base);`, right? Aren't you setting the `[[HomeObject]]` to `base`?

Comment: @JDB: No, I'm setting the `[[HomeObject]]` to `obj`, because `super` basically means `GetPrototypeOf([[HomeObject]])`

Comment: Ah... so to get foo to work without a reference error, you'd use `obj.foo = (function(){super.foo()}).toMethod(obj);` Or would that cause an infinite loop?

Comment: No, I think that's exactly what needs to be done (and how `obj.bar` is defined in my example)

Comment: @Bergi was `.toMethod` deprecated? I can't seem to find it implemented in any browser.

Comment: @nils: Yes, it's been removed from ES6 and deferred to later revisions (if at all). It seems Chrome did implement it once.

Comment: The lack of `toMethod` combined with static `super` makes it really difficult to copy a method from one class to another.

Comment: @trusktr: Yeah, it's the lack of `toMethod` that makes `super` static in the first place :-)

Comment: @Bergi is there a way to still implement this example? now it threw error: unexpected super.  it seems like the example is not a method definition thus super can't be used inside

Comment: @whales hardly, see the update. You're correct, `super` outside of method definitions is a syntax error now.

Comment: @jinbeomhong No, `Reflect` does not provide a workaround. What are you trying to do?

Answer (score -1):

My understanding is that `.toMethod` is like cloning a function. Consider the example in the source I posted,

```
class P { }
class C extends P {
    foo() {
        console.log("f");
        super();
    }
}
P.prototype.foo=C.prototype.foo;
(new C).foo();
```

Here you reference a subclass method `.foo` in the superclass, so when you call `.foo`, it will reference `P`'s `.foo` which is `C`'s `.foo` and you have just created a loop.

It seems like to solve this issue, you can use `.toMethod` which "clones" the function and give it a different `super`/"home" that you specifed:

```
P.prototype.foo = C.prototype.foo.toMethod(P.prototype);
```

now calling `(new C).foo()` would not go on forever.

Comment: ok there's only one thing I don't understand and then I'll get it. Is the **super()** representing the **class P**

Comment: I think now the method is belong to P so `super` would be not available at all.

Comment: before calling **.toMethod**

is this the same in es5:
`function P(){}`
`function C(){}`
`C.prototype = new P();`

`C.prototype.foo = function(){
 console.log('f'); 
 P(); 
}`
`P.prototype.foo = C.prototype.foo;`
`(new C).foo()`

Comment: I've now studied the draft for half an hour, and came to the conclusion that you'd need to do `super.foo()` instead of just `super()` - which would only work for (constructor) functions that inherit from other functions. Can anyone confirm (test?) this?

Comment: @Bergi - I have been thinking about that too, since super is just the constructor.

Comment: @Bergi: I know this is old and you probably know the answer by know, but just for reference: AFAIK `super()` *used* to be valid in every method and it would just call the parent method. But the spec changed recently and `super()` is now only allowed in the constructor `super.method()` is indeed the way to call parent methods in overridden methods.

Comment: @Bergi: Oh :D I think I read that thread but didn't realize or remember that you asked. NVM then :) (I just stumbled upon this question while browsering the ecmascrip-6 tag).