# calling overriden methods base in ES6

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ember-simple-auth

Give I have the following code:

```
import Authenticator from 'simple-auth-torii/authenticators/torii';

export default Authenticator.extend({
  restore: function(data) {

  },
  authenticate: function(provider, options) {

  },
  invalidate: function(data) {

  }
});
```

How can I, from inside the `authenticate` method, call into the base class `authenticate` method?

Comment: That `extend` function is not from ES6, is it?

Comment: think it is Ember.object.extend

Comment: you ledgend http://emberjs.com/guides/object-model/classes-and-instances/ that's what I was looking for :)

Comment: With ES6 though, you might consider [calling `toMethod`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27511704/1048572) and using the actual `super` keyword :-)

Answer (score 0):

In common ES5 case, not using `Ember.Object.extend` method with `this._super`, nor ES6 class inheritance, you must use standard [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) or [`apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) methods to realize it. So to call `authenticate` method of parent class you must add this to your child method:

```
Authenticator.prototype.authenticate.call(this /* some args here */);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is actually an Ember.js question and not specific to ES6. Jost call e.g.

```
this._super(provider, options)
```