# Can you alter an ES6 class definition to attach new instance methods?

Tags: javascript, class, methods, ecmascript-6

Is there any way to *retroactively* (i.e. after the class has already been defined) add instance methods to an ES6 class?

Consider the following class:

```
class Thing {}
```

I'd now like to attach a `hello` method to `Thing`, which would then be callable on its instances like so:

```
let thing = new Thing();
thing.hello();
```

Is it possible?

(Sure, I could make a subclass, but that's not what I'm asking here.)

Comment: Prototype inheritance still works the same as in ES5. Just add another property. Adding a *method* (in the ES6 sense) so that it works the same as if declared in the class literal is [a bit more complicated](http://stackoverflow.com/q/27511704/1048572) though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Or you could use **[Object.assign](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)**

```
Object.assign(Thing.prototype, {
    hello(arg1, arg2) {
        // magic goes here
    }
});
```

This is equivalent to

```
Thing.prototype.hello = function (arg1, arg2) {
    // magic goes here
};
```

Comment: Not exactly equivalent - you're using a method declaration. Oh, and `super` won't work.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the `prototype` as in ES5:

```
class Thing {
  hello () {
    console.log('Hey!');
  }
}

var t = new Thing();

t.hello(); // Hey!

Thing.prototype.goodbye = function () {
  console.log('Bye!');
}

t.goodbye(); // Bye!
```