# Is it possible to import class methods in ES2015

Tags: javascript, class, ecmascript-6

I'm creating a method in one module:

```
export function myMethod() {}
```

And instantiating a class in another module:

```
import {myMethod} from './methodFile';
class MyClass {
    constructor() {}
    myMethod // doesn't work
}
```

Is it possible to use `myMethod` as part of the `MyClass` class?

I'm trying to create the equivalent of the following code:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor() {}
    myMethod() {}
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, it is impossible to reference given values in `class` declarations.

However, `class` syntax is mostly syntactic sugar, and prototype inheritance works as always. You can simply put the method on the prototype object after the class definition:

```
import {myMethod} from './methodFile';
class MyClass {
    …
}
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = myMethod;
```

If your method needs to use `super`, you'll want to [use the `.toMethod` method](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27511704/1048572).

Comment: Btw, I'd recommend a `default` export if that's the only thing in your `methodFile`.

Comment: I recommend caution when stating classes are syntax sugar. That may be true now with transpilers; but not necessarily true with inbuilt browser implementation.

Comment: @Phil That's an implementation detail. The point is that despite the different syntax, classes don't introduce any new concepts, they're still just constructor functions with a prototype object.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it is possible to reference external methods inside the class:

```
// in methodFile.js:

module.exports = function myMethod() {
  console.log('running in the method!');
}
```

```
// in main file

const myMethod = require('./methodFile');

class MyClass {
    myMethod = myMethod;
}

const myClass = new MyClass();

myClass.myMethod(); // running in the method!
```

Answer (score -1):

Expanding on Bergi's answer. In case you have need of the `this` context in the function, use the arrow syntax instead:

```js
import {myMethod} from './methodFile';
class MyClass {
    …
}
MyClass.prototype.myMethod = () => myMethod;
```

These work but are a bit hacky; when using Typescript, you will get warnings for which I have not found solutions (which is not to say that there aren't any -- I'm still getting familiar with Typescript):

Probably solvable with some clever TS-declaration:

- Property 'myMethod' does not exist on type 'MyClass'.ts(2339)

When using `this.`:

- Object is possibly 'undefined'.ts(2532)