# Stubbing a javascript method with a super call

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, ecmascript-6, babeljs, sinon-chai

I'm trying to test an ES6 class method that calls a class method in its parent. For example:

Polygon.js

```
class Polygon {
    verifyDimensions() {
        this.allSidesValid();
    }
}
export default Polygon;
```

Square.js

```
import Polygon from './Polygon';
class Square extends Polygon {
    verifyDimensions() {
        super.verifyDimensions();
        if( this.height !== this.width ) {
            throw new Error( 'Not square' );
        }
    }
}
```

I want to test Square's verifyDimensions without calling Polygon's verifyDimensions. Testing with sinon/chai it seems babeljs is making a copy of the source method when the class is created. This makes it very difficult to stub out.

For example if I set up my test like so:

Square.spec.js

```
beforeEach( () => {
    sinon.stub( Polygon.prototype, 'verifyDimensions' );
    context.verifyDimensions = Square.prototype.verifyDimensions;
} );
```

the `super.verifyDimensions()` will still refer to `Polygon.prototype.verifyDimensions` and will error in a test.

Comment: Looks like they dropped `toMethod` which [could have done that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27511897/1048572).

Comment: @Bergi that's exactly what I need... d'oh

Comment: Babel looks up methods dynamically based on the prototype, it should work when you swap it out. I tried it with a manual `Polygon.prototype.verifyDimensions = function(){ console.log('spy'); };` and it printed my message.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Your example does work when the class definitions are in the same file. My code example should have been better for the behavior I'm seeing. My issue's more for classes imported from separate files. I've updated the example

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What does Function.prototype.toMethod() do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511704/what-does-function-prototype-tomethod-do)

Comment: You can swap out the module that exports the base class using SystemJS or proxyquire

Comment: how about 
    `sinon.stub(Reflect.getPrototypeOf(Square).prototype, 'verifyDimensions' );` ?