# Using super in an object created with Object.create

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Today morning I came across a [tweet from Šime Vidas](https://twitter.com/simevidas/status/730627477857550336) where he presented the following possibility of using `super` in object literals:

```
let A = {
  run() {
    console.log('A runs');
  }
};

let B = {
  run() {
    super.run();
  }
};

Object.setPrototypeOf(B, A);

B.run(); // A runs
```

This works, and assigning `B.__proto__ = A;` instead seems to work as well, both in Firefox and Chrome.

So I figured I could do the same with `Object.create`:

```
let A = {
  run() {
    console.log('A runs');
  }
};

let B = Object.create(A);
B.run = function() { super.run() };
```

Unfortunately, this results in an error in both Firefox:

> SyntaxError: use of super property accesses only valid within methods or eval code within methods

And Chrome:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: 'super' keyword unexpected here

The same happens when I try to pass a property descriptor object to the second argument of `Object.create`.

Semantically, they both seem equal to me, so I'm not quite sure what is happening (is it because of the object literal?).

Now I'm wondering, is this standard behaviour that is exactly defined (spec reference appreciated)? Are there some implementations missing for `Object.create`, or should object literals not work in the first place?

Comment: Well, `B` in your case is an `instance` (Okay, i know this word should not be used in JS-context) of `A`. So `B.run();` is the same as `A.run();`?

Comment: Check [this tweet](https://twitter.com/awbjs/status/730770661145088000) Which means that super can be used only from shortand definition methods.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Allen Wirfs-Brock, the editor of the ES2015 spec, was kind enough to [answer my question on twitter](https://twitter.com/awbjs/status/730770661145088000).

**Why is this an error?**

> super property references can only occurs in “concise methods” within a class def or obj lit http://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-function-definitions-static-semantics-early-errors

In that section of the spec, *Static Semantics: Early Errors*, there are four points that seem to be relevant:

- It is a Syntax Error if FormalParameters Contains SuperProperty is true.
- It is a Syntax Error if FunctionBody Contains SuperProperty is true.
- It is a Syntax Error if FormalParameters Contains SuperCall is true.
- It is a Syntax Error if FunctionBody Contains SuperCall is true.

So, super properties calls are neither allowed in function parameters, nor in regular function bodies. Thus my problem.

**Why is it necessary to use a method definition?**

> the reason is that `super` requires a back link from the method to its containing object. http://tc39.github.io/ecma262/#sec-runtime-semantics-definemethod

Meaning, if I have a super call in a method, and I assign that method to another variable, it still has to work:

```
let B = {
  run() {
    super.run();
  },
  walk() {
    console.log(typeof this.run);
  }
};

var run = B.run;
run(); // the 'super' binding still works, thanks to the internal MakeMethod

var walk = B.walk;
walk(); // 'undefined': the 'this' binding on the other hand is lost, as usual
```

This is specified in step 7 of the section defining the method semantics, which currently does not happen for regular assignments to an object:

7. Perform *MakeMethod*(closure, object).

**Could these semantics change in the future?**

> The back link is essential. Ways to dynamically set it were considered and could be again. Left out b/c error prone

So it would be possible that something like [`.toMethod`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27511704/what-does-function-prototype-tomethod-do), which can set the object `super` references to, could be introduced into the language after all, making my initial example with `Object.create` possible.

Answer (score 1):

I mean you can do this:

```
let A = {
  run() {
    console.log('A runs');
  }
};

let B = {
  run() {
    super.run();
  }
};

Object.setPrototypeOf(B, A);

let C = Object.create(B);
C.run(); //A runs
```

By the way, this also fails:

```
let A = {
  run() {
    console.log('A runs');
  }
};

let B = {
  run: function() {
    super.run(); // 'super' keyword unexpected here
  }
};

Object.setPrototypeOf(B, A);

B.run();
```

Comment: The first part of your answer does not seem to be relevant, the second is more interesting. Maybe it really has to be a method definition as defined in: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Answer (score 1):

Your answer covers most of it. `super` calls are only allowed in methods because methods are tied closely with the object they are declared on. That said, your best option would be to do

```
let B = {
    __proto__: A,
    run(){
        super.run();
    }
};
```

to declaratively create an object that has `A` as the prototype without requiring a potentially deoptimizing call to `Object.setPrototypeOf(B, A).`

Comment: Thank you for clarifying, I somehow assumed that this notion would be depotimizing as well. So as long as it happens within the initial definition of an object, it is still optimized by modern engines?

Comment: As far as I'm aware, yes, but it does require an engine that supports `__proto__` so it wouldn't work on IE<=10 for instance. You could probably port https://www.npmjs.com/package/babel-plugin-proto-to-create over to Babel 6 (It's Babel 5) if you needed to support ES5 environments though.