# I can't enable experimental JavaScript,

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-flags

I am trying to use experimental JS. I enabled flag *"Experimental JavaScript"* in chrome://flags, but **Function.prototype.toMethod()** doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. After `enabling` experimental features you have to `relaunch` chrome for the changes to take effect.
2. I believe `Function.prototype.toMethod(){...}` did not make it to the `standard` and I believe it is ripped out from the `experimental features` as well.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/27511897/11926958